# sed on not-owned file

Tags: linux, permissions, scripting

is it possible, to change a file in /etc with `sed -i` that I am not the owner of? However, I do have write permissions to that file.

Or as an alternative, how do I change a line in a file in /etc without having su-priviliges from within a script.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *very* likely that `sed -i` will create a brand new file then replace the original with it. That means you would have to have write access to the *directory* `/etc`, not just the file.

None of the tools that create a *new* file will work without that power, and that is rightly so: `/etc` is a very important directory and you probably shouldn't be playing there without permission :-)

One solution is to put your file somewhere where you *can* modify it, then just create a soft link to it from `/etc`. something like:

```
ln -s /my_directory/my_file /etc/my_file
```

You'll need root powers to create the link of course. The soft link will prevent the linkage from disappearing should you do a new-file/rename operation, since the soft link is simply a file containing the target path (which, unlike the inode, won't change with `sed -i`).

And this limits their power to changing that file and that file only. No possibility for security holes by opening up the permissions on `/etc`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. However I do not want to give the script-executing user +w on /etc

Comment: Oh ha... I do like the idea of the symlink! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you go the symlink route, make sure you lock down "my_directory" so somebody else can't replace the file.  There is a reason why /etc/ is locked down as hard as it is, and you subvert that at your own risk.

Comment: Note that you do not need any special privileges to create a symlink in, for example, /tmp that points to a file in /etc (so the "You'll need root powers to create the link" comment is bogus).  The rest is OK.

Comment: @JonathanL, it's not bogus. The method is to create the symlink in /etc pointing to somewhere else (that requires write access to /etc), *not* the other way around as you seem to have misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using "sed -i", you could try

```
sed ... > /tmp/foo && cat /tmp/foo > /etc/file
```

That way you're doing the actual changing of the file into a file in /tmp, and then writing that result to the file that you have write access but not replace access.

Comment: That's the way I go for now. This does not feel very "elegant" to me, but it works...

Comment: Use cp instead of cat, I suggest - it is a more direct expression of what you are doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, it looks like it needs to be cat if you don't have write permission on the directory.